# Want to create a function in class returns all rows of table

Tags: php, mysql

Like this:

```
class example {

public function func($query)
{
...
return $row;
}

}
```

How can i change below code:

```
public function func($query)
{
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
return $row;
}
```

I tried to push every row to array but it is hard to get rows from array;

Comment: What do you mean, `it is hard to get rows from array`?

Comment: `$query` is a result object? Once you `return` you exit the function so build the variable completely then return it.... or use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php then return.

Comment: can you show me example for pushing results to array getting them?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

**db.php**

```
class db {

public function get($query){

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
return $row;
}

}
```

**show.php**

```
$db = new db;

$row = $db->get("SELECT * FROM `posts`");

echo $row['title'];
echo "<br/>";
echo $row['body'];
```

***This is what i want to do***